# Fazer editor de texto com syntax highlight

Tags: javascript, html5, regex

Como posso fazer um sistema em HTML de syntax highlight para um editor de texto?

Eu pensei em utilizar uma tag `<pre>` com o `contenteditable="true"`, então utilizando RegEx eu substituiria as sintaxes do contentText, e modificaria o innerHTML...

Só que isso não dá certo.
Lembrando que quero fazer um sistema do zero, e não utilizar algum script pronto...Só preciso de uma ideia básica de como fazer.

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function highlight(){
            txt = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent;
            txt = txt.replace(/ (abc|teste) /gi, "<span style='color:#F00'>teste</span>");
            document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML = txt;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <pre contenteditable="true" onkeyup="highlight();">
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A implementação disso em si não é nem de longe uma tarefa simples, se for só colorir o texto mas sem permitir que o usuário edite, expressões regulares servem igual você ja fez, agora, pra edição vai ter mais dor de cabeça.

Você vai ter que capturar o pressionamento das teclas e criar toda uma lógica por trás pra simular o editor, por exemplo, manter uma lista de linhas e cada linha uma lista de tokens, editar ela de acordo com o pressionamento da tecla e posição da caret.

E aí conforme o usuário edita a linha, você teria que regerar a representação gráfica dela no container.

Algumas coisas para ler:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377344/how-do-i-write-a-parser-in-c
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: Eu consegui fazer algo utilizando uma textarea, e pegando o valor da mesma para ser apresentada na tag pre.
Com o que eu li sobre, acho que posso "redirecionar" o digitado no pre para a textarea...Acredito que sei como fazer isso.
Mas tenho uma duvida que gostaria de resolver antes de continuar..
Sei que não tem a ver com a principal, mas não queria fazer outro tópico...
Em CSS, tem como "obrigar" a cor das tags filhas?
Gostaria que dentro das aspas (" "), não mudasse a cor nas sintaxes.... Print: http://prntscr.com/86i0oo  
A propósito obrigado, os links me ajudaram muito. :)

Comment: Tem sim, o !important faz qualquer outra declaração ser ignorada. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/

Comment: Ah é, havia me esquecido do important rsrs.
Obrigado. :D